# Laravel regular expression whitespace

Tags: php, regex, laravel

```
$rules = array(
  'password' => array(
                  'required',
                  'min:6',
                  'regex:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*(_|[^\w])).+$/')
);
```

I am using this regular expression to allow (Contain at least one uppercase/lowercase letters and one number)

but I need help to validate that have only one whitespace (so continue whitespace makes invalid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `(?!\S*\s\S*\s)` which prohibits more than one whitespace (it allows 0 or one whitespace in the password).

```
'regex:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*(_|[^\w]))(?!\S*\s\S*\s).+$/'
```

If you want to force exactly one whitespace you'd do `(?=\S*\s\S*$)`.

Comment: If it answers your question, please accept the answer.